# How to get current date without using host system's date and time

Tags: javascript, date

I'm writing a node.js package that I want to distribute. I want a function to run at a certain time... but I don't want to use the client machine to determine date - rather I don't want this to be alterable.

Basically the script should break after a certain date and should not be able to be reverse by changing the PC's time. Is this possible?

P.S. I have no desire to create another server to serve this date. But that's the outcome I want to achieve.

Comment: `(await fetch('/', {'method': 'HEAD'})).headers.get('date')` Turn any api into a date api

Comment: appreciate this!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to convert any API into a date api:

```
(await fetch('/', {'method': 'HEAD'})).headers.get('date')
```

Replace '/' with any CORS capable API, or just '/' will work on most servers too.